# Does BIOS do anything when the Computer is shut down

Tags: boot, bios, shutdown

So, I start my computer. BIOS does POST, it boots the system, and from then on out works as a gateway between the OS and hardware, if I understood it all corectly.

If I now turn off the computer either by pressing the out button or by shutdown /s or anything like that, what does BIOS do.

Is BIOS involved in the shutdown process and does it do anything essential?

Thanks